# Bind variables results in full table scan in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, performance-testing

Checking the query cost on a table with 1 million records results in full table scan while the same query in oracle with actual values results in significant lesser cost.

Is this expected behaviour from Oracle ?
Is there a way to tell Oracle not to scan the full table ?

The query is scanning the full table when bind variables are used:

[image: The query is scanning the full table when bind variables are used]

The query cost reduces significantly with actual variables:

[image: The query cost reduces significantly with actual variables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pagination query. You want to retrieve a handful of records from the table, filtering on their position in the filtered set. Your projection includes all the columns of the table, so you need to query the table to get the whole row. The question is, why do the two query variants have different plans?

Let's consider the second query. You are passing hard values for the offsets, so the optimizer knows that you want the eleven most recent rows in the sorted set. The set is sorted by an indexed column. The most important element is that the optimizer knows you want **11 rows**. 11 is a very small sliver of one million, so using an indexed read to get the required rows is an efficient way of doing things. The path starts at the far end of the index, reads the last eleven entries and retrieves the rows.

Now, your first query has bind variables for the starting and finishing offsets and also for *the number of rows to be returned*. This is crucial: the optimizer doesn't know whether you want to return eleven rows or eleven thousand rows. So it opts for a very high cardinality. The reason for this is that index reads perform very badly for retrieving large numbers of rows. Full table scans are the best way of handling big slices of our tables.

> Is this expected behaviour from Oracle ?

Now you understand this you will can see that the answer to this question is *yes*. The optimizer makes the best decision it can with the information we give it. When we provide hard values it can be very clever. When we provide vague data it has to guess; sometimes its guesses aren't the ones we expected.

Bind variables are very useful for running the same query with different values when the expected result set is similar. But using bind variables to specify ranges means the result sets can potentially vary tremendously in size.

> Is there a way to tell Oracle not to scan the full table ?

If you can fix the pagesize, thus removing the `:a2` parameter, that would allow the optimizer to produce a much more accurate plan. Alternatively, if you need to vary the pagesize within a small range (say 10 - 100) then you could try a `/*+ cardinality (100) */` hint in the query; provided the cardinality value is within the right order of magnitude it doesn't have to be the precise value.

As with all performance questions, the devil is in the specifics. So you need to benchmark various performance changes and choose the best fit for your particular use case(s).